# tabularray wraps automatically after merging cells

Tags: tabularray

I want to merge the cells of the first row and the first column and the first row and the second column, and automatically wrap the cells after the merge

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={|Q[c,0.1\linewidth]|Q[l,0.4\linewidth]|Q[r,0.45\linewidth]|},rowspec={Q[c]Q[l]}}
        \hline
     \SetCell[c=2]{c}{This is a text.This is a text.This is a text.This is a text.This is a text.This is a text.This is a text.This is a text.This is a text.This is a text.This is a text.This is a text.This is a text.}   &  &DE  \\
    \hline
 ABC     &  ABC  &  ABC \\
    \hline
    \end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `hspan=minimal` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={|Q[c,0.1\linewidth]|Q[l,0.4\linewidth]|Q[r,0.45\linewidth]|},
  rowspec={|Q[c]|Q[l]|},
  hspan=minimal,
}
  \SetCell[c=2]{l}{This is a text.This is a text.This is a text.This is a text.This is a text.This is a text.This is a text.This is a text.This is a text.This is a text.This is a text.This is a text.This is a text.} &       &  DE  \\
  ABC    &  ABC  &  ABC \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I wonder why "DE in the top right cell is centered. Regarding the last column specification I expected that be right aligned.

Comment: Similarly is at bottom left cell. Why its content is not centered?

Comment: @Zarko Because alignments in `colspec` are reset by alignments in `rowspec`.

Comment: Hm, but according to `rowspec` "DE"  )in top right cell) should be aligned left, and "ABC" (in the bottom left cell) centered. But they are center and left aligned respectively. Now I suspect that in `rowspec={|Q[c]|Q[l]|},`  option `Q[l]` also overwrite `Q[c]` before it.

Comment: @Zarko With `rowspec={|Q[c]|Q[l]|}`, you get `row{1}={c}, row{2}={l}`.

Comment: Indead!  I need to read package documentation again :-(. Thank you very much for explanation! +1 for your answer.

Comment: Thank you very much